# How to generate qr_secret from caBLE QR code?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, qr-code, chromium, webauthn

I am developing Android authenticator. I am able to read caBLE QR code from webauthn. But I don't know that how to generate eid_gen_key from caBLE QR code to do StartAdvertsing in my Android authenticator.

Authenticator project is [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/android/features/cablev2_authenticator/). They are generating some eid_gen_key to StartAdvertsing from scanned QR code. But I couldn't understand the whole process. Is there any documentation to generate eid_gen_key from scanned QR code?

I got **fido://c1/r0W65gVNdMNqt2o8Hyfsg** from QR code. Kindly help me to proceed further.